# Save products in restricted user roles

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, magento2.4.5, user-roles

I am using Magento 2.4.5, where i have created user roles with access to catalog, marketing and sales. But those users are not able to save Products. When they try adding new product or editing existing products, they get the wait symbol and page stucks there without saving the product. If anyone has some info or solution about this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you've described could be due to a number of factors, so it might take some troubleshooting to get to the root of it. Here are a few steps you can take:

**1. Check Permissions:** Ensure that your user roles have the necessary permissions to save products. In Magento, go to System > Permissions > User Roles. Select the user role you've assigned to these users and double-check that they have access to all necessary resources related to product management.

**2. Clear Cache:** Sometimes, such issues may be resolved by clearing the Magento cache. To clear the cache, navigate to System > Tools > Cache Management and click on 'Flush Magento Cache'.

**3. Check for Extension Conflicts:** If you've installed any extensions recently, they could be causing a conflict. Disable any recently added extensions, clear the cache, and check if the problem persists.

**4. Check Console for Errors:** Open your web browser's console (right-click anywhere on the page and select Inspect or Inspect Element, then go to the Console tab) and see if there are any JavaScript or AJAX errors. This could provide more insight into what's causing the problem.

**5. Server Errors:** Check your server's PHP and error logs. These logs may contain information about any backend issues that are causing this problem. The location of these logs will depend on your server configuration, but your hosting provider or system administrator should be able to help you find them.

**6. Update Magento:** There may be a bug in your current version of Magento that's causing this issue. If there's an update available, consider updating to the latest version.

If the above steps haven't helped resolve your issue, don't worry, there are still a few more things you can do:

**Post More Details Here:** If you can provide additional details about the issue in this thread, it might help other community members identify the problem. Include any error messages you're seeing in your console or logs, the steps you've already taken to try and fix the issue, and any other relevant details.

**Look for Similar Threads:** Use the search function on this forum to look for similar issues. Someone else may have encountered the same problem and found a solution.

**Consult with a Magento Expert:** If you're unable to resolve the issue, you might want to consult a Magento developer or expert. While it may involve a cost, getting a professional to solve complex issues could save you time and potentially prevent bigger problems down the line.

**Magento Documentation and Support:** Magento provides a lot of documentation and resources online which can help you troubleshoot. You can find guides, references, and technical resources on their official website.

**Test Changes in a Staging Environment:** As a general rule of thumb, any major changes should be tested in a staging environment before being made on your live site. This helps prevent any disruptions to your business if the changes lead to unexpected results.

Remember, Magento's community is here to help. The more information you provide, the more likely it is that someone will be able to assist you. Please keep this thread updated with any developments, as it might help others facing the same issue in the future.